# How do you import Firefox/Chrome bookmarks into Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google-bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Firefox Bookmarks sync with Google Bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/163473/can-firefox-bookmarks-sync-with-google-bookmarks)

How do you import Firefox/Chrome bookmarks into Google Bookmarks? It looks like Google Bookmarks has some wonderful features, but it doesn't let people import their existing bookmarks from their browsers be it Firefox, Chrome or Internet Explorer.

There used to be workarounds for this, but no more: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/01/google-bookmarks-import-without-google.html

Can anyone think of a good way to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a Firefox extension that can help you synchronize your Firefox bookmarks with Google Bookmarks:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gmarks/

Comment: Is this only available for Firefox? No similar solutions for IE or Chrome users?