# How to import (and possibly sync) Chrome bookmarks into Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

This question has already been asked for Firefox ([Can Firefox Bookmarks sync with Google Bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/163473/can-firefox-bookmarks-sync-with-google-bookmarks)) and another questions that asked for Chrome/Firefox was marked as duplicate of the first question ([How do you import Firefox/Chrome bookmarks into Google Bookmarks?](https://superuser.com/questions/510375/how-do-you-import-firefox-chrome-bookmarks-into-google-bookmarks)).

I am looking for a solution to get Chrome bookmarks into Google Bookmarks. I hope to then use one of the Chrome extensions that let me use Google Bookmarks (so I can get tagging, etc).

Note I'm looking to get all of my bookmarks from Chrome to Google Bookmarks  (hundreds of them). So individually bookmarking them isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

### Google Bookmarks

**Google Chrome** bookmarks are separate from those saved in **Google Bookmarks**. While it's currently *not* possible to automatically sync these two sets of bookmarks, you *can* use a **bookmarklet** to easily create **Google Bookmarks** in **Google Chrome**.

Any time you visit a webpage that you want to save to your **Google Bookmarks** page, simply click the **bookmarklet** in the bookmarks bar.

Information directly from [Google Bookmarks](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100215)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to get all of my bookmarks from Chrome to Google Bookmarks  (hundreds of them). So individually bookmarking them isn't an option.